# Force team to follow site and conversations

Tags: following, subscribe

We have a sharepoint 365 mailing list and site.
It is imperative that all members receive the conversations to their inbox, not just the group folder.
Some of our teammates aren't the sharpest tool in the shed when it comes to technology.
1. Can I make their user follow the conversations remotely?
2. Can I send them a simple, direct link to subscribe?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I am wrong, but to me it sounds like your goal is to spam every user with "there is a new posting" emails? Setting up a Flow that is triggered by the creation of a new item, looking up the current list of users and sending an email to each of them is pretty easy. However there is no guarantee that the end user actually reads those emails ( setting up a delete rule in Outlook is also easy ;-) ). 
Setting up a GPO that opens the browser(s) on your news page could perhaps be an alternativ?

Comment: Thanks. It's not about spamming, but about letting everyone know about meeting summaries and Acton items.

Comment: I know :-) however that might not be the way the end user perceives it. I think it would be a good idea to provide people an opt out option